# How many open source projects are hosted on Maven?

Tags: java, maven, open-source

I couldn't find any public data about the number of hosted project in Maven. I'm particularly interested in Java programming language and open source projects.

Is there any official statistics?

Comment: Where should I ask that question? I'm always confused about what StackEchange forum should be used, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Maven Central's](http://search.maven.org/#stats) site has some stats, like that it contains over 100,000 unique artifacts, but it doesn't break it down by language or license.

Comment: Thanks! Couldn't find these statistics.

Comment: It's also important to note (depending on what you're using the stats for) that several build systems use Maven for dependency management, like Gradle and Leiningen. So a project's artifacts being hosted on Maven doesn't mean they're using Maven to build.